# Publish autohosted app to office store

Tags: app, autohosted

I read in below link I can't publish autohosted app to office store in "Can I submit an autohosted app for SharePoint to the Office Store?" paragraph is it true?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj591603(v=office.15).aspx#bk_q5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj591603%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_q5)

But I read in below link it's ok

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220044(v=office.15).aspx#VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220044%28v=office.15%29.aspx#VS2013)

If it's ok, how can I publish it?

Comment: Autohosted apps have been in beta and weren't meant to be used in production. What's more just recently it has been announced that they have been deprecated. With that you will need to convert your app to a provider-hosted app before you will be able to submit it to the Office Store.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported! Your second link does not talk about the store but about publishing your app to use it on your own (or other) tenant, but not to add it to the store for sale

Answer (score 0):

You should forget about auto-hosted apps

> We’re announcing today that the Office 365 Autohosted Apps Preview
>   program will end on June 30, 2014. After June 30th, developers will
>   not be able to create new autohosted apps in SharePoint. Apps that are
>   currently running in the service will not be affected or shut down.
>   We’ll post an update on this blog once we have an exact date of the
>   shutdown of autohosted apps running in the service.
>
> If you are currently using autohosted preview apps in a production
>   environment, we recommend that you follow this step-by-step on how to
>   transition autohosted preview apps to provider-hosted apps.

See [this post](http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/) for more details.